# Java keytool importcert: Illegal option

Tags: java, cmd, keytool

This is the command I am running in cmd:

```
 keytool -importcert  -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias microsoftgraph -file C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\cacerts.jks -keystore C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\security\cacerts -storepass changeit
```

The error is illegal option: Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\security\cacerts Has anyone got an idea as to what is going wrong?

Comment: Place anything with spaces in it in quotes, like `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\security\cacerts"`. Otherwise they are interpreted as different parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
keytool -importcert  -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias microsoftgraph -file C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\cacerts.jks -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass changeit
```